# Stretch a div to fit content in all screen size

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="whole">
  <div class="fst"></div>
  <div class="sec"></div>
  <div class="thd"></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.whole {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
.whole div {
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.fst {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    background: blue;
}
.sec {
    background: red;
}
.thd {
    float: right;
    width: 20px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Is there a way to stretch the `div.sec` to fit with the area left by `div.fst` and `div.thd` in any screen size? The width of `div.fst` and `div.thd` is fix in pixel.

Is there any solution with only css?

Really appreciate your helps!

Please see my `fiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/vHHcf/

Comment: Your fiddle and your code aren't the same

Comment: There is no solution for this.. in your way. But you can achieve it by using media queries.

Comment: Sorry, fiddle updated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be what you want.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/N5V5g/)

Given that you said `.fst` and `.thd` have fixed widths, you can use [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract the `40px` value from `100%`.

`.sec { width:calc(100% - 40px); }`

Updated CSS

```
.whole {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
.whole div {
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.fst {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    background: blue;
}
.sec {
    background: red;
    width:calc(100% - 40px);
}
.thd {
    float: right;
    width: 20px;
    background: blue;
}
```